# Sorting rows of numpy.array on the basis of a precise component

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array like the following

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[3.1,10,6.],[7.,4,8.1]])
```

and I want to re-order the rows in such a way that the second element of  the rows is increasing. So, I want the following output

```
[[ 7.   4.   8.1]
 [ 3.1 10.   6. ]]
```

because `4<10`.

The way I do it is to transform it into a list. Then, I could use `sort` and impose that the order must be done on the basis of the second element using `key` :

```
def f(x):
    return x[1]

b=list(a)
b.sort(key=f)
a=np.array(b)
print a
```

I don't like this approach, is it possible to do it without converting the array to a list, for example with `np.sort` or some other method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.argsort` will return the indices that sort a 1D array. 
So you want to sort `a` using the indices that will sort `a[:,1]` -- the second elements of each row in `a`.

You can do this with

```
a[np.argsort(a[:,1])]

# array([[  7. ,   4. ,   8.1],
#        [  3.1,  10. ,   6. ]])
```